# Add a Custom Field in Comment Box next to the Text area

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, comments, comment-form

Good Day.  I Recently try to figure out for adding the custom field in the comment box it working fine. Still I need to know how to add the custom field after the comment box. I am not sure how to do this.

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');

```
function change_comment_form_defaults($default) {

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

    $default['fields']['comment'] .= '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
            '
<input type="checkbox" style="margin:0px;height:auto;width:auto; position:relative;" name="privacy" value="1"/> I agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</p>';
    return $default;
}
```

When i Tried this above code this way itself is appear. 
[image]

How can i do this to show this field next to the comment box.
Any suggestion would be great.

**EDITED:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try use this action instead

```
<?php
    add_action("comment_form", "append_notice");
    function append_notice($post_id) {
        ?><p>Here is a notice</p><?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Angela, +1 Thanks for your Response when i use the comment_form hook is working perfect but it appear below the submit button of comment form. I edited my question with what i experienced exactly. Is there is a way to call this output above the submit button of comment form. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Vicky, I don't think there is such option is available unfortunately. The do_action only runs after the form has finished. The best you can do is to modify comments.php directly.