# Add a Custom Field in Comment Box AFTER text area BUT BEFORE Send button

Tags: actions, comment-form

I was inspired by this Q&A: [Add a Custom Field in Comment Box next to the Text area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109727/add-a-custom-field-in-comment-box-next-to-the-text-area) but I have to insert the custom field after the textarea but before the Send button.

I did not found the proper action to customize and I guess it not exists at all.

comment_form_after_fields puts my output before textarea
comment_form_after puts my output after Send button

Am I wrong?

```
    add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'test');

function test(){
    echo "TEST";
}
    add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'test');

function test(){
    echo "TEST";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609311/custom-comment-form-in-wordpress try this answer.

Comment: Thanks Ravs, this is a major redefinition, anyway it is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter `comment_form_defaults` and add your code to the textarea.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse_120049_extend_textarea' );

function wpse_120049_extend_textarea( $args )
{
    $args['comment_field'] .= '<p>Extra text.</p>';
    return $args;
}
```